# Problems Installing VSCode to Windows 10

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, windows-10

Can anyone help me out whilst I still have some hair left.

I have been running VSCode on Windows 10 since January.  Yesterday it attempted to update to the latest version 1.54 but failed.  VSCoce will now not run.

I am trying to re-install from the VSCode site installer.  However when I download and run the installer file windows gives an error saying the file is corrupt.

[Windows Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ox31i.png)

I seem to remember having this problem when installing the 1.52 version in January but I can find no reference to what I did to resolve this.  I believe I was pointed to an alternative install program, but I cannot find this now.

Please can anyone assist?

Many thanks.

Colin Murdoch.

Answer (score 0):

OK.  I have now managed to re-install VScode by downloading the .zip file and extracting all the elements into a directory within Program Files.  It remains to be seen if this will work properly as with no official install routine, nothing will have been added to the registry.  However the program loads OK and seems to recognise the PlatformIO extension that was already loaded.

I still don’t understand why I cannot run the official install routines.  There must be something odd about my Windows installation.

Answer (score 0):

check your antivirus program. I recognize that message. I had the same issue when trying to install an SQL server.